# Magento2: How to include js library + assets into static cms page via template?

Tags: magento2, jquery, phtml

i have a static page which was created via cms -> page.
I include a custom phtml template within the cms page

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}
```

Now i want to include a masonry gallery for example (https://vodkabears.github.io/galereya/)

**How can i include css, jss files from within the phtml file to the bottom of the theme where all the other assets like jquery, etc are?**

I tried several ways, i do **not** want the library to include in the whole theme, but only on the specific page. When i include the js/css files within the phtml file it gets included too early, before any jquery was loaded.

I hope to find someone who can help me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can add Layout Update XML update

> GOTO ADMIN -> Content -> Pages -> Edit page -> Design -> Layout Update XML

Write below content

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
  <script src="Namespace_YourModule::js/script.js" />
</head>
```

Save page.

clear cache.

Now you can see your css/js file is loaded only that cms page.

Answer (score 0):

Add below CSS file in **Layout Update XML**

```
<head>
  <css src="https://vodkabears.github.io/galereya/css/jquery.galereya.css" src_type="url"  />
</head>
```

Add below code in the **Content** field

```
<div id="gallery">&nbsp;</div>
<script>window.galereya || document.write('<script src="https://vodkabears.github.io/galereya/js/jquery.galereya.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#gallery').galereya({
                load: function(next) {
                    $.getJSON('https://vodkabears.github.io/galereya/images.json', function(data) {
                        next(data);
                    });
                }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

clear cache may require.